# Migrar codigo MySQL a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString]
    ( @string VARCHAR(4000), 
        @delimiter CHAR(1) 
    )
     RETURNS @output TABLE(Resultados VARCHAR(4000)
    )
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @start INT, @fin INT 
        SELECT @start = 1, @fin = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
        WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @fin = 0  
            SET @fin = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (Resultados)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @fin - @start)) 
        SET @start = @fin + 1 
        SET @fin = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
  END
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo? recibiste algun error? que se supone que haga esto?

Comment: Es muy importante que leas los enlaces que te pasaron. Por empezar, ¿Cual es tu pregunta?.

Comment: Pues nada esta Funcion yo la cree en mysql, de manera que lo que hice fue hacer el mismo proceso en sqlserver con este mismo codigo, y el resultado es el siguiente "invalid Stored Procedure Syntax" que al parecer el sql server detecta algun error de sintansis y no permite que cree la funcion, de manera que he buscando conversores de codigos y nada, entonces publique la funcion para ver si me ayudan con este tema.......esta Funcion la que hace es separar cadenas de string separadas por comas (,)